# Correct comma use with "but" and "that"

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

Compare these 3 sentences:

> 1. Both are based on librsync, but above that they behave quite differently.
> 2. Both are based on librsync, but above that, they behave quite differently.
> 3. Both are based on librsync, but, above that, they behave quite differently.

I found the first one hard to parse (I needed to read it more than once to actually make sense of it). The second is far easier, and the third has oh-so-many commas.

Comment: Rather than *above that*, I'd be more inclined to say, *beyond that*, *apart from that*, or *besides that*.

Comment: @Steve: “above that” is meant in a technical sense (in context, “both” refers to two programs built on top of the librsync library; the differences between the programs are in their upper layers, above librsync.)

Comment: Oh I see! In that case, I withdraw my previous comment. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In one school of thought, the first and third sentences are correct but not the second. We refer to Larry Trask's [*Guide to Punctuation*](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node14.html#SECTION00045000000000000000.) to substantiate this claim.

In the second sentence, the second comma is a mistake (it is not a listing/joining/gapping/bracketing comma). The last two commas in the third sentence are an optional pair of bracketing commas to set off the weak interruption *above that*.

Note that the joining commas before *but* in the first and third sentences are optional.

Comment: I don't disagree that the 2nd example is wrong, but the first misses the all-important comma that encourages one to pause.

Comment: I didn't mean that commas are the only means to pause. But putting a comma in that sentence makes it easier to understand. So I'm surprised that you find the first to be correct.

Comment: According to rules for comma usage, both usage in the second sentence are correct. Plus that you cannot read that sentence without the pause that second comma makes.

Comment: @Jasper: Are they? commas make pauses, as I've learned till now.

Comment: @Jasper: I still doubt that "In the second sentence, the second comma is a mistake" makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the list of rules linked - who says there are only those four, precise, species of comma? What analysis has been done to come to this conclusion? But in any case, to my mind the rules don't actually rule out the second example in the question: the first comma there is a joining comma joining *Both are based on librsync* to *But above that, they behave quite differently*. The second comma - the first comma of the second clause - is simply a bracketing comma separating off *but above that* (without which that clause still makes sense).

Comment: @psmears: That's exactly what i was writing. the first one is joining comma and the second one is bracketing comma -according to Jasper's link-, but my problem is that both commas are necessary there. The second one is necessary to set off a weak interruption.

Comment: @psmears: In sentence 2, the second comma can't be a bracketing comma: “but above that” is not a semantic unit, it's the conjunction “but” followed by the locative clause “above that”.

Comment: @Jasper: As long as these are optional, you can't say "the second comma is a mistake". and how you say the third one is correct when it has the same comma?

Comment: @Gilles: So would you call the following sentence wrong? *And after all, that was the original aim of the exercise.*

Comment: @psmears: I'm not a native English speaker, so I won't venture to call this sentence *wrong*, or to assert that the taxonomy cited by Jasper is complete. But it's not an example of a bracketing comma.

Comment: @Jasper Loy: Do you have any justification for these rules, or are they simply something someone has made up? I ask because (a) they seem to go against the evidence of general usage (searching COCA gives plenty of examples of, for instance, *<clause>, and after all, <clause>* which is on exactly the same model as (2), and (b) because the rules would seem to disallow the final comma in sentences like *He was strong, but after braving wind, fire, water and unfriendly people, he was in no state to socialise.* (in which the final comma is helpful because it avoids the reader having to reparse).

Comment: I searched in Google and on the first 10 pages, ", but above that," is used exactly like the second sentence.

Comment: Google is a loud of people.

Comment: FWIW, I agree with you, Jasper, that the second sentence shows a common mistake.  I explain my reasoning in my answer.  The 'above that' (or, as I'd prefer, 'beyond that') phrase can be omitted, so it is an adverbial phrase (I think), and should be surrounded by zero or two commas - not by one comma.  If Larry Trask also agrees, so much the better. I'm fairly sure that Carey (of ["Mind the Stop"](http://www.amazon.com/Mind-Penguin-reference-Gordon-Carey/dp/0140510729) fame) would also agree.

Comment: @Jonathan: What about my examples in my comment above? Do youconsider all the people writing *and after all* are wrong? Do you really think that that sentence is better with no comma after *people*?

Comment: @psmears: I'm not convinced the sentence structures are equivalent, though I'm not in any sense a qualified grammarian (beyond being a moderately competent user of English English as my native tongue).  The sentence you quoted in my view does not absolutely require the comma after 'strong' (but it is admissible), but it does require one after 'but' to balance the one after 'people' because it could also be 'He was strong but he was in no state to socialise' without the adverbial clause 'after braving ... people', or with the adverbial clause after 'socialise'.

Comment: @Jonathan: You *can* certainly put another comma after *but* (indeed you might prefer it - and I'm not saying I wouldn't!), but it is not *required*. Indeed I'm not sure how you could come to such a conclusion - try searching [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) (or indeed any other corpus) for ", but after" and ", but above": you will find plenty of examples of professional, literate writing with both comma styles. On what basis can one declare such a usage "wrong"?

Comment: @psmears: it's required because, as dissected on Larry Trask's page cited by Jasper, the phrase 'above that' needs a balanced pair of commas around it, or no commas at all; a single comma is simply *wrong*. The phrase is just 'above that'; it's not 'but above that' because the 'but' cannot be removed without destroying the sentence as a whole. _(From here on, we're going to have to agree to differ. It may be age-related; the rules I was brought up on, oh so many years ago, may not be the ones used by the young. Let the old guard hold to their prejudices, and rest assured your turn will come.)_

Comment: @Jonathan: OK I think we can agree to disagree. My point is that it seems very odd to say that a particular usage is "simply wrong", when (1) the only authority for what is right or wrong is what educated, articulate native speakers *actually use*, and (2) such speakers commonly employ that usage. It's not a generational thing, either - it doesn't take long browsing [Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/) to come up with examples from the early 19th century.

Comment: I agree with @psmears... the rules for commas are not so cut-and-dried, and the notion that bracketing commas **must** come in pairs is not based on actual usage, but rather on someone's mistaken idea of “logical consistency”. I would prefer punctuation option #2.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Boob's rationale for #2, but I might also suggest rewording the sentence to something more like:

> Although both are based on librsync, they behave quite differently.

In which case, you only need one comma.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep that structure, I would go with #2, but use `beyond` instead:

> Both are based on librsync, but beyond that, they behave quite differently.

Comment: Beyond would be correct in English. But if you mean 'above' in a technical sense, that the abstraction layers on top of librsync are different then 'above' might make more sense.

Comment: ah right, my mistake

Comment: @Claudia - I think you are right, it's just one possible alternative.

Comment: +1 for beyond; -1 for the punctuation option.

Answer (score 2):

> Both are based on librsync; apart from that, they behave quite differently.
>
> Both are based on librsync but beyond that they behave quite differently.
>
> Both are based on librsync but the layers above that behave quite differently.

The 'above' in the original feels clumsy - wrong; I much prefer 'beyond' if only a single-word change is allowed.  I prefer my first version to the other two.  My second example, without any commas, is extreme in its (lack of) punctuation, but is probably tenable.  With 'beyond' instead of 'above', options 1 and 3 in the question are OK.  My third option uses 'above', but the extra context added by 'layers' makes it sensible.

> Both are based on librsync but, beyond that, they behave quite differently.

I think this punctuation is also tenable (if you have any comma around 'beyond that' - or 'above that' in the original - then you need the pair since it is a parenthetical comment in the sentence and the pair of commas makes that clear).  If you dropped the comma-enclosed phrase, you would not *need* any punctuation:

> Both are based on librsync but they behave quite differently.

You could add a comma before 'but', and in times past that would have been added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second and third ones are acceptable, but in the third one the second *comma* is extraneous.

So, I would go with #2

> Both are based on librsync, but above that, they behave quite differently.

Answer (score 1):

First, I kindly recommend you to read this quote from "Gertrude Stein":

> And what does a comma do, a comma does nothing but make easy a thing that if you like it enough is easy enough without the comma. A long complicated sentence should force itself upon you, make you know yourself knowing it and the comma, well at the most a comma is a poor period that lets you stop and take a breath but if you want to take a breath you ought to know yourself that you want to take a breath. It is not like stopping altogether has something to do with going on, but taking a breath well you are always taking a breath and why emphasize one breath rather than another breath. Anyway that is the way I felt about it and I felt that about it very very strongly. And so I almost never used a comma. The longer, the more complicated the sentence the greater the number of the same kinds of words I had following one after another, the more the very more I had of them the more I felt the passionate need of their taking care of themselves by themselves and not helping them, and thereby enfeebling them by putting in a comma.
>   So that is the way I felt about punctuation in prose, in poetry it is a little different but more so …

And as Mike said, the second one sounds correct. like "a comma + a little conjunction ".

Answer (score 1):

I thought that it is not necessary to put a comma before 'but' if the sentences are not independent of each other?

Often when constructing a sentence with non-obvious grammar, it can be useful to deconstruct the sentence first (in your mind, of course).

This, to me, is correct:

> Both are based on librsync but they behave quite differently.

This, to me, is not:

> Both are based on librsync, but they behave quite differently.

Therefore I arrived at:

> Both are based on librsync but, above that, they behave quite differently.

Actually, I would have constructed the original sentence without the 'they' as well:

> Both are based on librsync but, above that, behave quite differently.

I wish I could give a more technical explanation, but I tend to judge these situations with my intuition.  (See what I did there?  An example of independent sentences conjoined by the use of 'but'.)

Comment: I really like your answer, but why is it so uncomfortable for me to accept your first example instead of the second one (which you rejected). I feel like I need that pause.

Comment: @Tshepang: I'm not sure why you are uncomfortable with it.  Perhaps it is because 'librsync' is a bit of a mouthful.  Try replacing it with 'apples'.  Or perhaps it is because you are used to pausing before/after a but.  Try pausing after 'but' rather than before it.  That is the way I would say this sentence with the 1st part qualified by the 2nd and the 2nd part requiring the 1st.

Comment: I'm used to pausing before *but*.